# Vim copy clipboard between mac and ubuntu over ssh

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, vim, ssh

I have been following [this guide](https://defuse.ca/blog/clipboard-over-ssh-with-vim.html) to try to get yanking to work across my ssh sessions.

I am using a mac laptop sshing into my ubuntu development machine.

I installed xclip, and added `X11Forwarding yes` to my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and added these lines to my ubuntu's ~/.vimrc

```
vmap "+y :!xclip -f -sel clip
map "+p :r!xclip -o -sel clip
```

Right now, I use this command: `ssh -X -i my.pem ubuntu@myserver.com`

When I try to yank a visual block, I would select the area with `v` and then press `"+y`

All I see in my vim console line is this when I do so: `:'<,'>!xclip -f -sel clip` and I don't see any copying done. I am not even sure if the command is executed. (When I look at :history I don't see the command being listed either)

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the content of [one of my gists](https://gist.github.com/romainl/96180b5b8e7722a7428c):

## Clipboard sharing on Mac OS X is easy.

### On the Mac

1. Install or update [XQuartz.app](http://www.xquartz.org/) and start it.
2. In the Preferences window, activate clipboard synchronization.
3. Quit XQuartz.app.
4. In iTerm.app or Terminal.app, connect to your remote machine with:

   ```
   $ ssh -X username@host
   ```

   and see the XQuartz.app icon pop-up in your Dock.

From now on, XQuartz.app will start automatically in the background when you use the `-X` flag, taking care of the clipboard synchronization for you.

### On the remote machine

1. If you don't already have it, install GVim. On Debian-based systems, use:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install vim-gtk
   ```

   The idea is *not* to use Gvim but installing it gets you everything you need to get clipboard sharing to work:

   - a minimal X
   - a Vim built with clipboard support
2. In Vim, synchronize the *unnamed* and *clipboard* registers by adding this line to `~/.vimrc`:

   ```
   set clipboard^=unnamed
   ```